# how is it possible to clear what was painted before?

Tags: delphi, controls, paint

I'm using Delphi and I'm building my own label component with class TControl.
Before I paint the text according to the properties (such as caption, font,  etc.) I want to clear paint rect like there is nothing at the place of component. I mean I want to make it like a glass so that the other components behind it will be displayed; and then paint the text. What should I do to paint other components that are placed behind my label to it?

Comment: Have you read Charles Petzold's seminal work on Windows programming? You'll find the answers there for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that, you need to do nothing. :-)

When you make a transparent label-like component, you best use the TGraphicControl base class. This is actually little more than a canvas to paint on. Whenever the content should be changed, you call the `Invalidate` method to repaint your control. This will call the `Paint` method that you can override. With every repaint, your control will be clear and transparent, except for the parts where you draw stuff in your `Paint` method.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you override and disable the background painting, then you dont need to do anything. It depends on what base-class you go for. Although you can simply use (in the Paint() method):

```
Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
Canvas.Brush.Color:=self.Color; //If you have a public color property
Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
```

You should also read up on TControlCanvas. Here is a website that deals with this topic more in depth: http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/75